# Can't figure out how to use getNewArrayFrom method with Scanner input?

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I don't know if I'm being vague or not, but what my main goal is is to create a program in which it asks the user for a set of words (any given amount) and then tells me which is first and last in the alphabet and which is shortest and longest. So far I have this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    double[] Words = getNewArrayFrom(Keyboard);
    displayList(Words);

    int choice = 1;
    while(choice > 0)
    {
        System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
        System.out.println("1) Enter a new list of up to over 9000 words.");
        System.out.println("2) Find the shortest, longest, and first and last alphabetically from the list.");
        System.out.println("0) Exit the Program");

        choice = Integer.parseInt(Keyboard.nextLine());

        if(choice < 0 || choice > 2)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Choice Number " + choice);
            choice = 1;
            continue;
        }
        if(choice == 1)
        {
            //Enter the Words one at a time
            System.out.println("Enter each of the words.");
            for(int i = 0; i < 9001; i++)
            {
                System.out.print((i+1) + "> ");
                Words = Keyboard.nextLine();
                Words = getNewArrayFrom(Keyboard);
            }
        }
        else if(choice == 2)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

}

Sorry for the length but I have no idea what I'm doing. I've written this all from memory and I don't really know what to do.

My main point is just trying to allow the getNewArrayFrom() method to create an array from the input strings if chosen. If you can at least point me in the way or direction of how to get it to print the shortest and longest and first and last alphabetical words then I would be forever greatful!

Sorry for the English it is not my first language.

Comment: Do you have any code for the function "getNewArrayFrom()"? I wasn't sure from your post if you are asking for help in creating that function, or if you made one but are having errors with it.  Can you clarify?

Comment: @kurtzbot No, I don't! :P 

I was actually asking how to create that function and apply it to the Scanner.

Comment: Why do you return an array of doubles? Do you mean `String[] Words = getNewArrayFrom(Keyboard)`?

Comment: I haven't tried that! I've also just started learning java 3 days ago, so I'm still struggling with the data types. Thank you! Also, it always says "The method getArrayFrom(Scanner) is undefined for the type word." Word is my class name. @kurtzbot

Comment: This also sounds like homework, is that the case?

Comment: It's sort of homework, while I'm not being graded on it, and it's not for a class, I have to have it done before I go back to school.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is pseudo-homework, I'll leave out details.

I am going to assume that all the user input will be from one line, ie., they provide an input string such as `apple banana orange grape`. I am also going to assume each word is separated by spaces.

I would used the Scanner to read a single line of input, look into [nextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29).  Then I would split the line that came back from the scanner by spaces, you can do this manually with a loop and `indexOf(...)` and `substring(...)` and store it in an array you created, or we can use the [split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to have the built-in Java String functions handle that part for us.

If you use `some_str.split(...)`, it will give us a String[] array automaticaly, so you can return it if you like.